# Get Array containing objects to normal object which have value as key in MongoDb result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this in

```
[
  {
    "date": "2022-12-03T12:16:52.403Z",
    "configs": [
      {
        "name": "Shubham",
        "values": [
          {
            "text": "172cm",
            "type": "Height",
          },
          {
            "text": "80kg",
            "type": "Weight",
          },
          {
            "text": "male",
            "type": "Gender",
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  {....},{....}
]
```

Want to convert `config` into objects like this

```
[
  {
    "date": "2022-12-03T12:16:52.403Z",
    "configs": {
       "name": "Shubham",
       "Height": "172cm",
       "Weight": "80kg",
       "Gender": "male",
    }
  },
 {...},{...},
]
```

I know how to do in Javascript array map method but need to understand how to do in mongoDb query ($project).

Comment: you want to change the format after you query ? if so you can this with an array map

Comment: Hey @cmgchess, i know how to do in JS array method, but wanted to learn how to do same thing in mongo query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach

1. First `$unwind` the `configs` since it contains only 1 element
2. In the `$project` stage use `$arrayToObject` to convert the `[{k:'key1',v:'value1'},{k:'key2',v:'value2'}]` to `{key1:'value1',key2:'value2'}`.
3. The `$map` stage is used to convert the field names in `values` array to the above format.
4. `$concatArrays` is used to concat the `name` field and value before converting array to object so that it becomes `[{k:'name',v:'Shubham'},{k:'Height',v:'172cm'}...]`

[Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hm1o6DZ_4kP)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$configs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date: 1,
      configs: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $concatArrays: [
            {
              $map: {
                input: "$configs.values",
                as: "el",
                in: {
                  k: "$$el.type",
                  v: "$$el.text"
                }
              }
            },
            [
              {
                k: "name",
                v: "$configs.name"
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
arr=[];
yourOutPutJson.forEach(function(b){var obj={};obj.name=b.configs[0].name;b.configs[0].values.forEach(function(c){obj[c.type]=c.text});arr.push(obj)});
```

Comment: I know how to do in JS array method, but wanted to learn how to do same thing in mongo query

Comment: Please remove the javascript tag from the question :)